# Hífen como nome de coluna em banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, select, progress-4gl

É possível trabalhar com colunas que possuam hífen (`-`) dentro de um select?

Exemplo: `SELECT fm-codigo, descricao FROM ems2cad.pub.familia`

*Banco de dados Progress*

Estou realizando a consulta utilizando PHP via ODBC, ja tentei diversos meios, como utilizar crase, aspas simples, colchetes, chaves mas nenhum resolve, os resultados que obtenho são erros dizendo que a coluna não foi identificada ou nenhum valor retornado.

**Código utilizado para testes abaixo:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste de relatórios</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php
            $connect = odbc_connect('ems2cad', *user*, *pass*);
            $sql = "SELECT fm-codigo, descricao FROM ems2cad.pub.familia";
            $result = odbc_exec($connect , $sql);
        ?>

        <table width=”600” height=”500”>
            <tr>
                <td>fm-codigo</td>
                <td>descricao</td>
            </tr>  

            <?php
                while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo odbc_result($result, 'fm-codigo');?></td>
                <td><?php echo odbc_result($result, 'descricao');?></td>
            </tr>       
            <?php     
                }
                odbc_close($connect);
            ?>
        </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deveria funcionar. Verifique se vc consegue dados sem usar um desses campos, só como teste. Meu palpite é que vc não está realmente conseguindo se conectar ao banco (alguém estou uma conexão SQL pra vc? Vc consegue pegar dados de alguma tabela?).

Comment: @bupereira eu consigo trazer as informações se utilizo o select all, portanto sim, estou conectado ao banco, no entanto para tratar esses campos que possuem hífen em joins e clausulas where preciso conseguir chamá-los e é aí onde está minha dificuldade. Outro exemplo, neste mesmo código, se eu deixo o select assim SELECT 'fm-codigo', descricao, ele me retorna duas colunas, uma repetindo os valores 'fm-codigo' e outra trazendo os valores da descricao que constam no banco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente obrigado a todos que se disponibilizaram a ajudar.

Entrei em contato com um suporte na qual foi me passada a seguinte dica:

> Neste caso o "fm-codigo" do seu exemplo deverá chegar no banco de dados
>   Progress com as apas duplas, porém agora é necessário adaptar sua string para que envie 
>   estas aspas junto.

Deste modo o resultado final foi:

```
$sql = 'SELECT "fm-codigo", descricao FROM ems2cad.pub.familia';
```

Solução simples, mas custosa. Obrigado!